# Pl Sql delete query

Tags: plsql

I need to do a delete in a Oracle database, but i only need to delete a specific fields of the table, right now i´m using the following script

```
delete TABLE where co_id in ('XXX')and SUBSTR(CS_PENDING_STATE,-1)='p';
```

The problem is that this query also deletes all the row of the CS_PENDING_STATE field, and i need only to delete the information attached  to the CS_PENDING_STATE field, that satisfied the SUBSTR.

How could i get this donde ???

Thank you.

Comment: You dont delete specific fields. You set them as null

Comment: Hi thank you, but i dont get it, could you please post a example??

Comment: you want to remove the value from a column or you want to delete the whole row ?

Comment: i want to delete all the values of a specific column(CS_PENDING_STATE),  which end up with 'p' not the whole row, as happen right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an update statement to set a particular column value to blank/null.

**If it is a nullable Field:**

```
update TABLE Set CS_PENDING_STATE = null where co_id in ('XXX')and SUBSTR(CS_PENDING_STATE,-1)='p';
```

**If it is a non-nullable field:**

```
update TABLE Set CS_PENDING_STATE = '' where co_id in ('XXX')and SUBSTR(CS_PENDING_STATE,-1)='p';
```

Comment: Hi. with the following query i manage to 'Delete' what i needed thank you so much for your help !!!    update table set CS_PENDING_STATE = null,
CS_PENDING_PARAM = null
where co_id in ('XXX') 
and SUBSTR(CS_PENDING_STATE,-1)='p';